# Merge lists in a nested list to 1 element in a list

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have the following nested list:

```
[('A+', 2), ('O+', 1), ('AB-', 1), ('AB+', 1), ('B-', 1)]
```

and would like to change it to a list that looks like this:

```
['A+ 2', 'O+ 1', 'AB- 1', 'AB+ 1', 'B- 1']
```

or

```
['A+ (2)', 'O+ (1)', 'AB- (1)', 'AB+ (1)', 'B- (1)']
```

is this possible? if so what would be the best way to approach it?

Comment: @Samwise, I believe that should give `TypeError` until type cast to `str`

Answer (score 2):

Works well with list comprehension:

```
a = [('A+', 2), ('O+', 1), ('AB-', 1), ('AB+', 1), ('B-', 1)]
b = [f'{i} {j}' for (i,j) in a]
c = [f'{i} ({j})' for (i,j) in a]
print(b) 
print(c)
```

prints

```
['A+ 2', 'O+ 1', 'AB- 1', 'AB+ 1', 'B- 1']
['A+ (2)', 'O+ (1)', 'AB- (1)', 'AB+ (1)', 'B- (1)']
```